# DynamoDB Sort key so that I could query the last item by date

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The following DynamoDB table has a partition key equal to date so I could easily query day by day. I know items with the same partition key are stored in the same partition and are ordered by their sort key.

However, the sort key in this case is wrong because `TransferId` is not something like a date that I could sort.

What sort key should I use so I could query the last item for a specific date? 'Exchange:Time'?

```
+----------+------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
|    PK    |                    SK                    | Account |                  Address                   | AddressTag | Exchange | Instrument | Network | Quantity  |           Time            | TransactionFee |                           TransactionId                            |            TransferId            | TransferType |          UpdatedAt           |
+----------+------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
| 20221217 | Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | main    | 0xF76d3f20bF155681b0b983bFC3ea5fe43A2A6E3c | null       | Binance  | USDT       | ETH     | 97.500139 | 2022-12-17T14:59:12+00:00 |            3.2 | 0x46d28f7d0e1e5b1d074a65dcfbb9d90b3bcdc7e6fca6b1f1f7abb5ab219feb24 | 1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 |            0 | 2023-01-27T18:00:00.5930186Z |
| 20221217 | Binance:4747f6ecc74f4dd8a4b565e0f15bcf79 | main    | 0xF76d3f20bF155681b0b983bFC3ea5fe43A2A6E3c | null       | Binance  | USDT       | ETH     | 3107.4889 | 2022-12-17T15:38:23+00:00 |            3.2 | 0xbb2b92030b988a0184ba02e2e754b7a7f0f963c496c4e3473509c6fe6b54a41d | 4747f6ecc74f4dd8a4b565e0f15bcf79 |            0 | 2023-01-27T18:00:00.2944534Z |
+----------+------------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+-----------+---------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

I suppose the code should be something like the following:

```cs
var date = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

var request = new QueryRequest
{
    TableName = "transfers-dev",
    KeyConditionExpression = "#date = :date",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "#date", "PK" } },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> { { ":date", new AttributeValue { S = date } } },
    ScanIndexForward = false,
    Limit = 1
};
var response = await client.QueryAsync(request);

return response.Items.First();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date as a partition key is not very useful, it essentially caps your throughput to 1000 WCU and also doesn't give your query flexibility like `give me the data for the last 18 hours`.

You should choose something useful as partition key, and choose date as your sort key.

| PK | SK | data | gs_pk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | 2022-12-17T14:59:12+00:00 | data | 1 |
| Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | 2022-12-18T14:59:12+00:00 | data | 1 |
| Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | 2022-12-19T14:59:12+00:00 | data | 1 |

You can now say give me all the data for a given binance in a given time frame. If you require a lookup where you want all the binances for the last given amount of time you can create a GSI and use a random or static value as partition key. They more keys you use the more throughput you will be capable of consuming.

| gsi_pk | SK | PK | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-17T14:59:12+00:00 | Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | data |
| 1 | 2022-12-17T14:59:12+00:00 | Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | data |
| 1 | 2022-01-26T14:59:12+00:00 | Binance:1b56485f6a3446c3b883f4f485039260 | data |

#### Get most recent data:

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE.MYINDEX WHERE gsi_pk = 1 DESC`

#### Get data for a given day:

`SELECT * FROM MYTABLE.MYINDEX WHERE gsi_pk = 1 AND SK BEGINS_WITH '26.01.2022'`

#### Note

Having a single value for your GSI partition key will also limit your scalability, if you intend on writing more than 1000 items per second (assuming items < 1KB) then you will have to shard the index key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But then how can I do reporting for let's say 26.01.2022?

Comment: Thanks! Does it make sense for the Transaction Id to be PK?

Comment: Use something that us useful for your PK. Something that suits one of your primary access patterns. Such as give me all the data for a given transaction, or for a given binance.

Comment: I got your point about the partition key. It is used for partitioning the data physically and in order to get best performance it should spread workloads among all/most partitions. Otherwise performance might suffer.

Comment: I will have the following access patterns: 1) Get user transfer by TransferId; 2) Get all user transfers by Exchange and optionally a specific instrument; 3) Get all user transfers by date range 4) Get all transfers by Exchange and Account name

Comment: I kinda don't know what to choose for a partition key. I read https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/ and there was a kinda similar example and what they say about `TransactionId` is that in most cases it is not going to be used for querying purposes and that's correct. So I kinda lose the ability to use the partition key to perform a fast lookup of data.

Comment: by looking at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html, the example they gave is `[country]#[region]#[state]#[county]#[city]#[neighborhood]` and the description is `This would let you make efficient range queries for a list of locations at any one of these levels of aggregation, from country, to a neighborhood, and everything in between.`, which means whatever I need to query should be concatenated to the sort key.